# Placing Text on Multiple Imported PDF Pages with iTextSharp

Tags: itext

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I am trying to create a web application that utilizes iTextSharp to import a multi-page pdf, the place text on the different pages, in other words a certain text for page 1, different text for page, etc.  I've successfully imported the pdf, but the text is escaping me.  Here is my code:

```
            PdfReader reader = null;
        Document sourceDocument = null;
        PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

        int startPage = 1;
        int endPage = 2;

        try
        {

            string sourcePdfPath = Server.MapPath(path);
            // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
            reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);

            // For simplicity, I am assuming all the pages share the same size
            // and rotation as the first page:
            sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

            // Initialize an instance of the PdfCopyClass with the source 
            // document and an output file stream:
            //
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, ms);
            //
            //pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument,
            //    new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            sourceDocument.Open();

            // Walk the specified range and add the page copies to the output file:
            for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
            {
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }

            PdfContentByte cb = pdfCopyProvider.DirectContent;

        PdfReader reader = null;
        Document sourceDocument = null;
        PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

        int startPage = 1;
        int endPage = 2;



        try
        {

            string sourcePdfPath = Server.MapPath(path);
            // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
            reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);

            // For simplicity, I am assuming all the pages share the same size
            // and rotation as the first page:
            sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

            // Initialize an instance of the PdfCopyClass with the source 
            // document and an output file stream:
            //
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, ms);
            //
            //pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument,
            //    new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            sourceDocument.Open();

            // Walk the specified range and add the page copies to the output file:
            for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
            {
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }

            PdfContentByte cb = pdfCopyProvider.DirectContent;

            //select the font properties 
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);

            //write the Patient Name
            cb.BeginText();
            //put the alignment and coordinates here 
            cb.ShowTextAligned(3, "Hello", 200, 200, 0);
            cb.EndText();

            sourceDocument.Close();
            reader.Close();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.pdf");
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
            Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }

            sourceDocument.Close();
            reader.Close();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.pdf");
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
            Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In short: to add some extra content to pages of an existing document, use a `PdfStamper` instead of that `PdfCopy`.

Comment: Example?  I'm not sure how to import the existing document without PdfCopy.

Comment: There are plenty of `PdfStamper` examples on the [official iText web site](https://itextpdf.com). The web site examples usually refer to the original question for which the example was written. In this case: an example that is used to add a header/footer. This being said: `PdfStamper` is part of an old iText version? Why aren't you using the latest version (being iText 7)???

Comment: I'm using 5.5.13 as it was the version pulled down by Visual Studio 2015 NuGet manager.  Part of my confusion is the examples based on varying versions.  What would you suggest?